# How to wait for all tasks of an NSURLSession to complete?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsoperationqueue, nsurlsessiontask

Why is `NSURLSession` operation queue empty after creating and resuming an NSURLSessionTask?

Is there a way to tell if an NSURLSession has tasks pending?

The goal is to wait for multiple tasks to complete, but this doesn't work:

```
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [self.session uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request];
[uploadTask resume];
// this prints "0"
NSLog(self.session.delegateQueue.operationCount)
// this returns immediately instead of waiting for task to complete
[self.session.delegateQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
```

Comment: OK, I may have found a clue at  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1504 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19414486/1033581 regarding the fact that `NSURLSession` can't be solely used for batching.

Comment: DispatchGroup is what you need :) Found this link on very google result http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution that avoids invalidating the session, using the suggested `DispatchGroup`.

(answer is in Swift, while question is in ObjC ... but it's the same logic)

Note that when using, `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:`, we need to implement an `URLSessionTaskDelegate` and `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)`. So, to simplify the answer, I will demonstrate the use of `DispatchGroup` with `uploadTaskWithRequest:from:completionHandler:`.

```
// strong reference to the dispatch group
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

func performManyThings() {
    for _ in 1...3 {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.com")!)
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        let uploadTask = self.session.uploadTask(with: request, from: nil) { [weak self] _, _, _ in
            self?.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        uploadTask.resume()
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        // here, all the tasks are completed
    }
}
```

Comment: For any body else who wants to use DispatchGroup, I found this article helpful in explaining how to use it - https://medium.com/@oleary.audio/simultaneous-asynchronous-calls-in-swift-9c1f5fd3ea32

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy as long as you don't care about reusing the session and don't mind doing things asynchronously:

- Call `finishTasksAndInvalidate` on the session.
- Implement the `URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError:` method in your session delegate to do whatever work you need to do after the last task finishes.

That said, the problem with your code above is that the session doesn't have any operations until it starts the first fetch, which can't happen as long as your code is blocking the run loop.  You generally should not attempt to use NSURLSession synchronously.  It is almost always the wrong way to solve things.  :-)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, because it's true that I didn't specify about reusing the session. Truth is, I needed to reuse it, so I've accepted a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Cœur's solution, if you just need to wait for all request responses before continuing code execution you don't need to use a queue. Instead of:

```
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    // here, all the tasks are completed
}
```

you can simply use:

```
// Waits that all requests finish.
dispatchGroup.wait()
```

And continue code execution after this point.